# Java async servlet: Wait for a specific event

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, wait, notify

EDIT:
Edited the question in response to @maress answer below.

I have a web service in java (async enabled), which when called performs a call to another service asynchronously. In my Controller I have this:

```
private boolean receivedEvent = false;
private final Object SYNC = new Object();

public Callable<String> doStuff()
{
     callSomeAsyncFunction();

     return new Callable<String> ()
            {
                @Override
                public String call() throws Exception {

                    synchronized (SYNC)
                    {
                        while (receivedEvent == false)
                        {
                            SYNC.wait();
                        }

                        receivedEvent = false;
                        System.out.println("RETURN");
                        return "ok";
                    }
                }
            };
}

public void onMyEvent(MyEvent event)
    {
        synchronized (SYNC)
        {
            receivedEvent = true;
            System.out.println("RECEIVED");
            SYNC.notify();
        }
    }
```

EDIT: The notification never gets through. System.out.println("RETURN") is never called. The events are being received ('RECEIVED' is shown).

Now all I want to do is wait for the `callSomeAsyncFunction()` to finish executing. When done, it triggers an event on the handler `public void onMyEvent(MyEvent event)`.

Any suggestions? I am not even sure if my approach makes sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronize always on a final instance.

```
private MyEvent myEvent;
private final Object SYNC = new Object();

public Callable<String> doStuff()
{
     callSomeAsyncFunction();

     return new Callable<String> ()
            {
                @Override
                public String call() throws Exception {

                    synchronized (SYNC)
                    {
                        while (myEvent == null)
                        {
                            SYNC.wait();
                        }
                        return "ok";
                    }
                }
            };
}

public void onMyEvent(MyEvent event)
    {
        synchronized (SYNC)
        {
            myEvent = event;
            SYNC.notifyAll();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thx, now I am not getting any errors, but the notification does not work. I never reach 'return "ok";'

Comment: Probably because callSomeAsyncFunction() never calls your onMy/evnt(MyEvent) function.

Comment: Post the entire code? And please make sure MyEvent is never null at the point of calling onMyEvent(MyEvent) function.

Comment: Just edited the question. I entirely removed the handling of MyEvent to avoid any side effects. I just want to log to the console. Still not working.

Comment: At what point do you register the callable to the callback event?

Comment: This is done in Spring Integration somewhere else. callSomeAsyncFunction() tries to send a message over a channel via Spring Integration, which in turn calls the onMyEvent when the message was sent successfully. As far as I can tell the message IS being sent and onMyEvent IS being called.